# A flawed theorem about regular languages

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages

I am struggling with this question for a very long time and just can't find the flaw. So I am given a false Theorem:

> The language $\{awwa \mid w \in \{a,b\}^* \}$ is regular.

Well, that part is obvious, we can prove that the language is not regular using the pumping lemma.

The question I am asked is to find the flaw in the "proof" for this theorem:

> Let
>
> $\qquad L_1 = \{ aw \mid w \in \{a,b\}^* \}$
>
> $\qquad L_1^R = \{ wa \mid w \in \{a,b\}^* \}$
>
> Let $L_2 = L_1 L_1^R = \{ awwa \mid w \in \{a,b\}^*\}$ be even-length palindromes that begin and end with an $a$.
> Since $L_1$ is regular, and the class of regular languages is closed under reversal and concatenation, we conclude $L_2$ is also regular.

Can you find the flaw? I could build a DFA for $L_1$ and $L_1^R$, so I know they are regular. And regular languages are closed under reversal and concatenation.

But, however, $L_2$ is still not regular, so where is the mistake in the "proof"?

Comment: Try writing down some words from $L_1 \cdot L_1^R$ -- you'll notice quickly what's wrong. (Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/271/add-short-reference-for-latex-commands) for a short introduction.)

Answer (score 2):

The concatenation of $L_1$ and $L_1^{\mathrm{R}}$ is not $\{awwa\mid w\in\{a,b\}^*\}$.

Comment: it's not? How come?

Comment: @user14896 What is the definition of the concatenation of two languages?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that for some languages $L_1$, $L_2$, $LL = \{uv \;\colon\; u \in L_1,\;v \in L_2\}$. Back to your question, is it the case that for every $au \in L_1$ and $va \in L_1^R$ that $auva$ is an even length palindrome that begins and ends with $a$?